# What to substitute for glob_t and glob() on port to Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, porting, glob

I have some code like this snippet:

```
#include <glob.h>

glob_t globBuf;
const int result = glob(remoteFileName.c_str(), 0, 0, &globBuf);

if (result == GLOB_NOSPACE) {
  ...
} else if (result == GLOB_NOMATCH) {
  ...
} else {
  ...
}
```

But I'm not finding `glob.h` on windows.

What would I use on Microsoft Windows to provide equivalent functionality to port this code from Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glob` is a POSIX specific thing, and does not exist on Windows. On Windows look at the [`FindFirstFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and it companion functions.

Comment: Does Microsoft Interix SUA include glob()?

Comment: @WilliamKF I don't know, can't seem to find a list of available APIs.

Comment: flag
 
@WilliamKF: It does, but keep in mind that unlike CMD.EXE, SUA's shells conform to POSIX and do globbing themself; so their use are usually quite different between the two environments.